# Perl or bash script for posting SOAP

Tags: bash, perl, curl, soap

I need to create bash or perl script for posting SOAP request. The case is that it must read specific numbers from file (line by line) and post request for each row until end of file. So basically in `request.xml` query file i need to replace the value of on tag 
`<ICCID xmlns="">VALUE NEEDS TO BE REPACED HERE</ICCID>`

And in the `text.txt` file where the values must be read has content like:

89370010100004370782
89370010164904370786
89370010100004370793
...and so on

My XML file:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsk="http://www.mskj.it/xsk">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsk:CertChangeStatusRequest id="63791" time="2016-10-21T14:17:47.831Z">
     <ApplicationID>TEST</ApplicationID>
     <ServiceID>TEST</ServiceID>
     <ICCID></ICCID>
     <ChangeStatus>Revoke</ChangeStatus>
     <ReasonCode>0</ReasonCode>
     <Comment>test</Comment>
      </xsk:CertChangeStatusRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I thought of using curl for posting SOAP.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How to make script replacing the value in tag and posting it consistently to server url.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I know how to post one query using CURL: curl -d @post.xml -H "Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" http://myserver.test:8080/service

Answer (score 0):

May be the request based on this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#File opening Structure and learn make it simplify these lines.
my $queryfile = "request.xml";
open(QRY, $queryfile) || die "Can't open/found: $!\n";
local $/; $_=<QRY>; my $qrytext=$_;
close(QRY);

while(<DATA>)
{
    my $mtch_no = $_;
    $qrytext=~s/(<ICCID xmlns=\"\">)([^<>]*)(<\/ICCID>)/$1$mtch_no$3/g;

    # And delete the value from `text.txt` file
    # You can do your work here (post the request here)
}

open(OUT, ">$queryfile") || die "Can't open/found: $!\n";
print OUT $qrytext;
close(OUT);

__DATA__
89370010100004370782
89370010164904370786
89370010100004370793
```

There is also one way to tie the text in a file none other than module `tie::file` for single shot for I/O. I hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Gives:

Can't modify concatenation (.) or string in scalar assignment at autoposter.pl line 7, near ""request.xml";"
Execution of autoposter.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: you couldn't post comment as answer. Delete that answer.

Comment: I have right now:
`#!/usr/bin/perl use strict; use warnings; 
#File opening my $queryfile = "xsk_revoke.xml"; 
open(QRY, $queryfile) || die "Can't open/found: $!\n"; 
local $/; $_=<QRY>; my $qrytext=$_; 
close(QRY); my $infile = "iccid.txt"; 
open (INPUT, $infile) || die "Can't open $infile: $!"; 
while(<INPUT>) { my $mtch_no = $_; $qrytext=~s/(<ICCID\>)([^<>]*)(<\/ICCID>)/$1$mtch_no$3/g; } 
open(OUT, ">$queryfile") || die "Can't open/found: $!\n"; 
print OUT $qrytext; 
close(OUT);`

How to delete curl posted value after?